# python: count hours between two date columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Im new using stackoverflow

I want to calculate per id and month nbr of hours that an employee is off, so technically the hours between (end and beg) two timestamp, what is the best way to get it please.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2']
   ,  'beg':['2021-01-01 00:00:00',
   '2021-02-03 00:00:00','2021-02-04 00:00:00','2021-02-05 00:00:00',
   '2021-02-06 00:00:00','2021-03-05 00:00:00','2021-04-01 00:00:00'],
      'end':['2021-01-02 00:00:00 ',
   '2021-02-03 12:00:00','2021-02-04 10:00:00','2021-02-05 10:00:00',
   '2021-02-06 10:00:00','2021-03-07 10:00:00','2021-05-08 00:00:00']}
```

Expected output

```
x1 01/2021  24
x1 02/2021  22
x2 02/2021    20
x2 03/2021     58
x2 04/2021 552
x2 05/2021 168(08/05/2021 = 24*7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create hours by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and then aggregate counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.id,pd.date_range(r.beg, r.end, freq='H', closed='left')) 
                                                for r in df.itertuples()]).reset_index()
df1.columns=['date','id']

df1 = df1.groupby(['id', df1['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Or use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x.beg, x.end,freq='H',closed='left'), axis=1)

df1 = df.explode('date')
df1 = df1.groupby(['id', df1['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')]).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
   id     date  count
0  x1  01/2021     24
1  x1  02/2021     22
2  x2  02/2021     20
3  x2  03/2021     58
4  x2  04/2021    720
5  x2  05/2021    168
```

EDIT:

Solution for better performance - is created `Series` in hours for differency, then repeat `index` values with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then add hours timedeltas to hours:

```
df.beg = pd.to_datetime(df.beg)
df.end = pd.to_datetime(df.end)
dif = df.end.sub(df.beg).dt.total_seconds().div(3600).astype(int)
         
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(dif)].copy()
df['date'] = df.beg + pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='H')
print (df)
    

df1 = df.groupby(['id', df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')]).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
   id     date  count
0  x1  01/2021     24
1  x1  02/2021     22
2  x2  02/2021     20
3  x2  03/2021     58
4  x2  04/2021    720
5  x2  05/2021    168
```

EDIT:

This solution should working in large DataFrame:

```
df.beg = pd.to_datetime(df.beg)
df.end = pd.to_datetime(df.end)
df['dif'] = df.end.sub(df.beg).dt.total_seconds().div(3600).astype(int)
      
N = 5000

out = [] 
for n, g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))/N):

    g = g.loc[g.index.repeat(g['dif'])].copy()
    g['date'] = g.beg + pd.to_timedelta(g.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='H')
    s = g.groupby(['id', g['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y')]).size()
    out.append(s)

df = pd.concat(out).sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
```

Comment: thank you but i need to do it per month as my expected output.

Comment: IN april we should count from 08/04/2021 to 30/04/2021. And i may: from 01/08/2021 to 08/05/2021(08/05/2021 = 24*7). Please tell me if im not clear !

Comment: seems your results are different from my original expected output. Thank you !!

Comment: Thank you i will test and for 04/2021 it is still 720.

Comment: I updated it, was responding here and forget the original post. it is may.

Comment: when i tried to run you first code got this error **KeyError: 'date'**

Comment: Got you thank youu! when i run the code on df of 65500 rows it takes too much time and then sho this message **The kernel seems to be stuck. It will restart automatically.** do you have an idea pleasE?

Comment: both. the same:/

Comment: Same thing :/ :/

Comment: do you mean i should split my dataframe by 5000 rows?

Comment: @biwia - added one idea to answer, I hope working now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code works for you:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['x1', 'x1', 'x1', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2', 'x2']
   ,  'beg':['2021-01-01 00:00:00',
   '2021-02-03 00:00:00','2021-02-04 00:00:00','2021-02-05 00:00:00',
   '2021-02-06 00:00:00','2021-03-05 00:00:00','2021-04-01 00:00:00'],
      'end':['2021-01-02 00:00:00 ',
   '2021-02-03 12:00:00','2021-02-04 10:00:00','2021-02-05 10:00:00',
   '2021-02-06 10:00:00','2021-03-07 10:00:00','2021-05-08 00:00:00']})
df.beg = pd.to_datetime(df.beg)
df.end = pd.to_datetime(df.end)
df["difference"] = df.end - df.beg
print(df.difference/ np.timedelta64(1, 'h'))
```